# Continuous function from real to natural number

Tags: general-topology, functions

How can you prove that the only continuous function from real number with the Euclidean topology to natural number with the cofinite topology is the constant function (without metrics)?

I tried to use disconnections and the fact that the preimage of a closed set is close if the function is finite, but I can't find anything, as N is connected with the cofinite topology...

Thank you!

Comment: That is [surprisingly nontrivial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected).

Comment: The question is answered right here "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719723/show-for-all-continuous-f-mathbbn-tau-c-to-mathbbr-tau-st/1719743 " maybe it help

Comment: there is some answere right here " https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719723/show-for-all-continuous-f-mathbbn-tau-c-to-mathbbr-tau-st/1719743 " maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

For $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, the set  $\{ f^{-1}(x) | x \in \mathbb{N} \}$ partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into a countable nummber of closed sets, which by a theorem of Sierpinski(?) requires the partition to have just one part.